# VBA - throwing exceptions to grab more numbers for output errors

Tags: vba, excel, exception

I have code which forces the length of any CT values to be a length of 4 numbers following "CT-", and does the same with TL values to a length of 6 following "TL-". If it is too short, 0s are added after "TL-"; if it is too long, 0s are deleted from right after "TL-"; the same goes for CT.

The problem I have run into is that I need to grab maximum two numbers that come after a dash which comes after the CT value. It needs to only be after that dash and only grab the values immediately following or it will mesh them together.

My previous question solving for issues with the "TL-" code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193307/vba-throwing-exceptions-for-specific-errors-in-working-code-isnumeric-issue/31195421#31195421) if that is useful at all.

**Example:**

Current Output

```
Start:               Output:
CT-0087(TC-7988)     CT-0087
CT-0067-02           CT-0067
CT-0076-REV01        CT-0076
CT-0098-1 A          CT-0098
```

Desired Output

```
Start:               Desired Output:
CT-0087(TC-7988)     CT-0087
CT-0067-02           CT-0067-02
CT-0076-REV01        CT-0076-01
CT-0098-1 A          CT-0098-1
```

So there should always be a "-" and a maximum of 2 numbers to grab, but I would only want it to grab it if the dash is immediately following (for potential error: CT-0087 should not become CT-877988 due to grabbing numbers or numbers after a dash) and I do not know how to throw an exception for that particular issue. Any thoughts would be very helpful!

In code:

```
'force length of TL/CT to be 6/4 numbers long, eliminate spaces

            Dim str As String, ret As String, k As Integer

            For k = 2 To StartSht.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
                ret = ""
                str = StartSht.Range("C" & k).Value

                ret = ExtractNumberWithLeadingZeroes(str, "TL", 6)
                If ret <> "" Then
                    StartSht.Range("C" & k).Value = "TL-" & ret
                Else

                    'for CT numbers
                    ret = ExtractNumberWithLeadingZeroes(str, "CT", 4)
                    If ret <> "" Then
                        StartSht.Range("C" & k).Value = "CT-" & ret
                    End If

                End If
            Next k
```

Function:

```
Public Function ExtractNumberWithLeadingZeroes(ByRef theWholeText As String, ByRef idText As String, ByRef numCharsRequired As Integer) As String

' Finds the first entry of idText in theWholeText
' Returns the first number found after idText formatted
' with leading zeroes

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim thisChar As String
Dim returnValue As String
Dim tmpText As String
Dim firstPosn As Integer
Dim secondPosn As Integer

    returnValue = ""
    firstPosn = InStr(1, theWholeText, idText)
    If firstPosn > 0 Then
        ' remove any text before first idText, also remove the first idText
        tmpText = Mid(theWholeText, firstPosn + Len(idText))
        'if more than one idText value, delete everything after (and including) the second idText
        secondPosn = InStr(1, tmpText, idText)
        If secondPosn > 0 Then
            tmpText = Mid(tmpText, 1, secondPosn)
        End If
        ' Find first number
        For j = 1 To Len(tmpText)
            If IsNumeric(Mid(tmpText, j, 1)) Then
                tmpText = Mid(tmpText, j)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        ' Find where the numbers end
        returnValue = tmpText
        For j = 1 To Len(returnValue)
            thisChar = Mid(returnValue, j, 1)
            If Not IsNumeric(thisChar) Then
                returnValue = Mid(returnValue, 1, j - 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        'force to numCharsRequired numbers if too short; add 0s immediately after idText
        'force to numCharsRequired numbers if too long; eliminate 0s immediately after idText
        ' The CLng gets rid of leading zeroes and the Format$ adds any required up to numCharsRequired chars
        returnValue = Format$(CLng(returnValue), String(numCharsRequired, "0"))
    End If

    ExtractNumberWithLeadingZeroes = returnValue

End Function
```

Comment: In order to code for your exception, you need to figure out, with regard to your exception, what is the defining characteristic that makes it an exception?  Is the the `(`?  Is it the `TC`?  Or is it something else?

Comment: Right, and that is exactly where I am confused. I have thought of it as... if it encounters a "-" immediately after the fourth number, get up to 2 numbers immediately following that "-" . I simply do not know how to write a code for that kind of specific exception.. Any ideas or thoughts on if that is even a good way to approach thinking about the exception @RonRosenfeld ?

Comment: If that algorithm works, it would be fairly simple to code using regular expressions.  Do you want to do the same thing with your TL codes?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld , the TL codes work perfectly with the code that is in my question so, if possible, I'd like to not mess with that part of it

Comment: and awesome! thanks for your advice! do you think you could help me figure out the code for that?

Comment: I will post something in a few minutes.  Working on the 4-digit requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that will return what you specify above:

===========================================

```
Option Explicit
Function ExtractCode(S As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .ignorecase = False  'could be true if you want
    .Pattern = "(CT-)\d*?(\d{4})(?!\d)(?:(-)\D*(\d{1,2}))?.*"

    S = Replace(S, "CT-", "CT-000") 'add leading zero's to pad to 4 if necessary

    If .test(S) = True Then
        ExtractCode = .Replace(S, "$1$2$3$4")
    Else
        ExtractCode = ""
    End If
End With
```

## End Function

Here are some examples:

[image]

Here is a formal, brief explanation of the Regex:

### (CT-)\d*?(\d{1,4})(?!\d)(?:(-)\D*(\d{1,2}))?.*

```
(CT-)\d*?(\d{1,4})(?!\d)(?:(-)\D*(\d{1,2}))?.*
```

Options: Case sensitive; ^$ don’t match at line breaks

- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6ntC.png) `(CT-)`

  - [Match the character string “CT-” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `CT-`
- [Match a single character that is a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d*?`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) `*?`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6ntC.png) `(\d{1,4})`

  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d{1,4}`

    - [Between one and 4 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{1,4}`
- [Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!\d)`

  - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d`
- [Match the regular expression below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6ntC.png) `(?:(-)\D*(\d{1,2}))?`

  - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
  - [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6ntC.png) `(-)`

    - [Match the character “-” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `-`
  - [Match a single character that is NOT a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\D*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
  - [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6ntC.png) `(\d{1,2})`

    - [Match a single character that is a “digit”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d{1,2}`

      - [Between one and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{1,2}`
- [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`

$1$2$3$4

- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$1`
- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 2](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$2`
- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 3](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$3`
- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 4](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$4`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: wow, scared me at first but thank you for the very detailed explanation. I have never used Regex before. Could you help me understand a little more? So obviously I would put the function at the bottom of my code but..how would I call it in my code? @RonRosenfeld

Comment: @user4888 I'm not sure as I did not go through your code in any detail.  But you could feed this function the unmodified line; and, if there is a valid CT code (that being defined as CT- followed by at least one non-zero digit), it will return the properly formatted and filtered code.

Comment: okay, i'll try that! I have the code looking for TL and CT values to alter and leaving anything else as is. My concern is being able to figure out how to specify that if there is a CT value ... and then how to reference the function. I'll try to figure it out! Thank you so much for your help! @RonRosenfeld

Comment: I don't think you need to have other code looking for CT values;  If you feed the function a line that doesn't contain CT code, it will just return a null string.

Comment: ah yes but if say the cell says HOLDER 4.52 1/2", I need it to return that information. That is why I have it currently set up that it prints out whatever the cell value is and thenlooks for TL and CT values that may need altering @RonRosenfeld

Comment: Can lines contain both?   If you just delete `Else
        ExtractCode = ""`  then the function will return the line unchanged if a CT- code does not exist.

Comment: Actually, you have to eliminate all of the `If ... else ... end if` statements and just leave the |ExtractCode = .Replace(S, ... `